# PHP short hand to append a value to an array only if a certain condition meet

Tags: php

I need to add an element to an array only if a condition is met.

I want to add an element of a given needle exists in a haystack.

The following is the traditional way of doing it.

```
if(in_array($options_array[$i], $meta_info_keys))
{
 $array = append_to();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary expression:

```
expr1 ? expr2 : expr3;
```

Which means:

```
if expr1 then expr2 otherwise expr3
```

Visualization:

[image]

Your statement can be rewritten as:

```
$array = (in_array($options_array[$i], $meta_info_keys)) ? append_to() : $array;
```

It's generally recommended to avoid ternary statements if they make your code unreadable. In this case, it doesn't really matter, though.

Comment: Wont this clear out the array if the condition is false?

Comment: @RyanS: That was not what I meant. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`$array = in_array($options_array[$i], $meta_info_keys) ? append_to() : $array;`