# PHP nesting if statements - is there a better way?

Tags: php

Could I nest these PHP IFs in a better to understand/ more logical way?

```
 if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']))
    {
        $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
        $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

        if (is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds))
        {
            $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
            $response = json_encode($total);
            header(“Content-Type:application/json”);  
            echo $response;
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: This `header(“Content-Type:application/json”);` will throw a 500 error. Change it to `header("Content-Type:application/json");` - Those curly quotes are beautiful, yet *deadly*.

Comment: You shouldn't use `is_int` on something that's coming from `$_GET`, because all `$_GET` values are strings (or arrays for that matter). Use `is_numeric` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary statements to make this a little bit nicer. The logic is the same, but you can reduce the number of lines required, at the expense of a little readability.

Some other important points to note:

- You had smart quotes. `“` is not the same as `"`. The former will not be parsed by PHP -- and will most likely throw an Internal Server Error.
- **Don't use [`is_int()`](http://php.net/is_int)** — it will lie to you. When you're working with user input data, you'll be fetching it from `$_POST`, `$_GET` superglobal arrays. All those values will be stored as strings. `is_int()` treats a string containing a number, for e.g., `"42"` as  as a string, and will return false. Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) instead.

Updated code:

```
$numwelds = isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) ? $_GET['numberofwelds'] : '';
$numconwelds = isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']) ? $_GET['numberofconwelds'] : '';

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. Two Q's: Why have you repeated `$_GET['numberofwelds'] ` on the top line? Just realised that I'm using `$_POST`, so should I just swap this with `$_GET`?

Comment: @mattnewbie: **1.** First `isset()` part checks if the variable is set, and if so, assign it to `$numwelds`. See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22233554/1438393) for an explanation of the ternary syntax. **2.** I just used whatever you had in question. If you're using `POST`, then use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the checking in the first `if`. The first condition check if both fields exist and the second one check for the type.

```
if ( (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds'])) &&
     (is_int($_GET['numberofwelds']) && is_int($_GET['numberofconwelds']) )
{
    $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
    $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header(“Content-Type:application/json”);  
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could invert conditionals like many IDEs (for example PHPStorm) tell you to, so you could do it like:

```
if (!isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) || !isset($_GET['numberofconwelds'])) {
    exit;
}

$numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
$numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

if (!is_int($numwelds) || !is_int($numconwelds)) {
    exit;
}

$total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
$response = json_encode($total);
header("Content-Type:application/json");  
echo $response;
```

As you can see, the nesting was almost eliminated. However, I encourage to use more functional (or object) way of doing things. Simple example:

```
if (checkGetData($numwelds, $numconwelds)) {
    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type:application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
}

function checkGetData($numwelds, $numconwelds) {
    if (isSetAndNumeric('numberofwelds') 
         && isSetAndNumeric('numberofconwelds')) {
        $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
        $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isSetAndNumeric($property) {
    if (isset($_GET[$property]) && is_numeric($_GET[$property])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Writing code in such way is much more readable, especially as projects get bigger and more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Im not an "@" fan but maybe

```
    if($numwelds=@$_GET['numberofwelds'] && $numconwelds=@$_GET['numberofconwelds'] &&         is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds)) {
            $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
            $response = json_encode($total);
            header("Content-Type: application/json");  
            echo $response;
            exit;
    }
```